# PRAGMA journal_mode=OFF is not working.why?

Tags: sqlite, sqlite-journal-mode

I am running SQLite3 version sqlite-3.6.12 and I have successfully ported it to my OS. The problem I am seeing is that when I execute the command "PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF" it returns "OFF" but I am still seeing *.db-journal files being created. It is critical that these files are not created for the purpose of my project. When I step through the code sqlite3PagerJournalMode is returning PAGER_JOURNALMODE_OFF so I am wondering if setting journal_mode=OFF should still produce these files or if there is something else that I am missing.Please help

I also tried PRAGMA main.journal_mode = OFF and PRAGMA journal_mode = MEMORY.But the journel file is creating as such !!!!

Answer (score 2):

> Many pragmas have both temporary and
>   permanent forms. Temporary forms
>   affect only the current session for
>   the duration of its lifetime. The
>   permanent forms are stored in the
>   database and affect every session.

[When to use pragmas on sqlite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883527/when-to-use-pragmas-on-sqlite)

Answer (score 1):

Try to set exclusive access (PRAGMA locking_mode=exclusive), sometimes journal is created for external locking.

Comment: Thanks To respond.I already tried with this option But no differences.
My version of sqlite is sqlite-3.6.12.whether the particular version has any problem?

Comment: yes.I am doing everything in my application codes only.I can set the default_cach_size(5000) through command line.but when i am setting JOURNEL mode or temporary mode as different than default,then It is not giving that values next time.But cache size is showing like the previously(5000).